# Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, [unknown, boolean, any]>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9

Using Angular 9 I need to check a condition based on two methods that returns two observables:

```
    return zip(this.authService.isSignedIn(), this.authService.getRole()).pipe(
      map(([isSignedIn, role]: [boolean, string]) => isSignedIn && role && role.toLowerCase() === 'admin')
    );
```

But I get the error:

```
 Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, [unknown, boolean, any]>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked your imports? Are you sure that the zip() params are observables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's common mistake, you have missuesed the import, ensure that you are importing `zip` from `rxjs` not from another namespace

```
Import {zip} from "rxjs"
```

Comment: Spot on ... I was importing it from 'rxjs/operators'. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're importing `zip` directly from `'rxjs'`. This is not an operator but Observable creation method.
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip

There's also `zip` operator in `'rxjs/operators'` but you don't want that in this situation.
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/zip